# How can I pair handlers for mouse event in CSS

Tags: javascript, xhtml

According to XHTML 1.0 transitional events handlers should be paired. I.e the event handler `onmouseout` should be paired with `onblur`. How can I do that?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: You should provide a link to the source for this "pairing" claim.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what this has to do with CSS specifically, so your title is a little confusing.  You can pair event handlers in an HTML element by assigning JavaScript handlers for both events.  Normally you see `onmouseover` paired with `onmouseout`, and `onFocus` paired with `onBlur`.  See the [onmouseout Event example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp) at w3schools.com.  The two event handlers are paired in the tag

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
```